# Concatenating 2 strings together

Tags: c++, string

I have two strings:

```
string word;
string alphabet;
```

`word` has some input that I passed on to; let's say `"XYZ"`.

`alphabet` has the alphabet except `XYZ`, so it's `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW"`

When I tried to concat them with "+=", all I get is `word` (i.e. `"XYZ"`). I want to make it look like this:

```
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
```

What am I doing wrong? Code is basicly this vvvv

===========================encryption.cpp=================================================

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "encryption.h"
#include <string>

encryption::encryption()
{
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

}


string encryption::removeletter(string word,char letter)
{
    //remove letter
    string temp;
    int indis=0;
    for(int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(word[i] != letter)
            {
                temp[indis]=word[i] ;
                indis++;
            }

    }

    word=temp;

    return word;
}

This is the function i have proplems with :

    void encryption::encrypt(string word)//main.cpp is just calling this atm
    {
        string temp;
        int pos;
         //getting rid of the repeating letters
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if( (pos = temp.find(kelime[i])) < 0)
                temp += word[i];
        }
        word=temp;//that ends here
        //taking words letters out of the alphabet
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            alfabet=removeletter(alfabe,word[i]);

        }
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;alfabet[j] !='\0'; j++)
                if(alfabet[j+1] =='\0') alfabet[j]='\0';
        }

        /* I tried += here */
    }
```

===========================encryption.h====================================================

```
#ifndef encryption_h
#define encryption_h
#include<string>

    class encryption

    {
    public:
        encryption();

        void encrypt(string word);
        string removeletter(string word,char letter);
        //some other functions,i deleted them atm

    public:
            string alphabet;
            string encryptedalphabet;
            //staff that not in use atm(deleted)

    };

#endif
```

===========================main.cpp======================================================

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "encryption.h"
#include <string>

string word;
encryption encrypted;
cin>>word;
encrypted.encrypt( word);
```

Comment: That's not merging. That's concatenation.

Comment: It’s really completely unclear what your question is. Can you please work on presenting your problem more *clearly*?

Comment: What are you missing, not sure. But what is missing is that you didn't post the code that doesn't work. Is that really so hard to do? Isn't it *obvious* that you should post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: @Shahbaz Are you a mind reader or something? Where did you get all that information from?!

Comment: @KonradRudolph, if you read both versions, I didn't add anything. I just changed from ugly writing to English.

Comment: May be you are doing `alphabet += word;` instead of `word += alphabet;`, no way to know unless you post the code.

Comment: can someone explain what's the last loop for? i is not even used...

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is how you do it, you must be doing something else.

```
string word = "XYZ";
string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW";
alphabet += word;
cout << alphabet << "\n";
```

output

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Comment: when i do that it just giving me word i have no idea whats going on it shouldnt be doing that

Comment: @user2265881 Print out the values of `alfabet` and `word` before `+=` and after. I bet you will find that one of your variables doesn't have the value you think it has.

Comment: i did and funny thing is its printing them just fine but it just doesnt merge them

Comment: @user2265881 You need to post enough code so that someone else can take your code and run it. I would just post the whole program. Otherwise everyone is just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Use

word.[append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)(alphabet);

Note that when you want to concatenate many strings, it's more efficient to use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream) to avoid unnecessary string copying.

Comment: -1'd c++ strings are mutable, using assign like this is pointless.

Comment: ... and what is "unnecessary string copying"? What does stringstream do? It also contains a buffer for the data and copies it all the same.

Comment: @Dariusz What assignment are you talking about? And about string streams: precisely, they use a preallocated buffer internally, strings don’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the one that got edited in the meantime; and for stringstream - it is more efficient, but the data is copied nonetheless. The gain is less memory alloc/realloc, not copy amount

Comment: @Dariusz No, the efficiency *does* come from less copying, and it’s a huge factor. Reallocation implies that all the old data has to be copied over to the new buffer. The less you reallocate the fewer buffer copies you need to perform. Of course, that only makes sense within a loop.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are right; realloc does not always mean copy though, same buffer can sometimes be realloc'ed and stay at the same memory place

Answer (score 0):

```
string word = "XYZ";

string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW";

word += alphabet;
```

Now you can print 'word', and you will find your answer.